# Developing a custom keyboard (like Swype) for Windows Phone 7.1 Mango

Tags: c#, keyboard, windows-phone-7.1

Having recently bought a Windows Phone I can say the one feature I sorely miss from my Android phone is Swype. This was a custom keyboard where you trace your finger over the keyboard to create words. Its very fast and basically I think its awesome.

Anyway! There is no Swype on WP7... The reason for this I hear is because it is impossible to change the keyboard programmatically in Windows phone. I would like to know from the community if things have changed or are likely to change in this area, or if there are any workarounds to programmatically inject a custom keyboard into the UI to allow input with any text field.

Disclosure - if it becomes possible I would like to develop a swype like app, however it would likely be because I miss it so much rather than as a commercial project!

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to officially create a new keyboard that functions outside of your app. So, if you plan to release this in the marketplace, then it's not currently possible. You might be able to create a homebrew app that does this, but I don't think it would be very easy to replace the standard keyboard system wide. Of course, even if you did manage the homebrew version, it definitely wouldn't be allowed on the Marketplace.

Comment: So I believe. I was wondering if there were any 'creative solutions' to get around this limitation. Very frustrating really! I miss Swype!

Comment: Nothing I can think of off the top of my head. You could create an app which is just the specialised keyboard and let the user enter their message. The user can then copy that message, from within your app, and paste it anywhere else (e.g. a text message/email). I believe Swype also has a couple of patents (check external links section): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swype

Comment: FYI I found an app, Slydr but suffers from inability to swap the keyboard as mentioned :(

Answer (score 2):

You're limited by what Microsoft allows you to alter and they don't allow you to alter the keyboard.  Furthermore Swype is a patented and very advanced technology that would be a humongous project for a single developer to work one.  It's a good idea as lots of people like Swype but WP7 isn't Android.

Comment: Patents are one thing but hugely complicated? Looks to me like nearest neighbour algorithm between a traced path and known list of paths of words from a dictionary :-P

Comment: I didn't say hugely complicated but I did say it was advanced and would be a very big project for a single developer.  I think that you are understating the complexity of a good auto-correction/auto-learn algorithm though.